# Rake Routes project_attachment_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a project_attachment_path

In my routes I have:

```
resources :projects do
collection do
    get "attachments/:id/:style.:format" => "attachments#download", :as => :attachment
end
end
```

**Problem is in RAKE ROUTES:**

```
attachment_projects GET    /projects/attachments/:id/:style.:format                   {:action=>"download", :controller=>"attachments"}
```

It's backwards? Any ideas what I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is backwards? This question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be standard behaviour, it's the same thing I see with Rails 3 here.

```
resources :auditions do
  get 'preview', :on => :collection, :as => 'preview'
end
```

Will give me 'preview_auditions' as the route ('preview_audition' if on member) which seems to make sense.

Perhaps you could rename your :as => :attachment to match the desired outcome? Re-arranging your routes could also work - giving your projects a nested attachments resource would allow you to have routes such as 'download_project_attachments_path(@project)'